# Performance while downloading images from server to imageview

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, lazy-loading, android-imageview

I am new to android .  I was trying to implement an Asnyc tasks which downloads a set of 5 images at a time by parsing a json which s returned from the server. 
There are is  a next button on the interface which displaces the 2nd 3 4 images in the  image view.

1. The current code works, fine but I think it  can be made more efficient if all the 5 set of image is downloaded at once.
2. Is it possible that when I click next button that time if the image is not yet downloaded then an animated gif or a loading circle is displayed ?

Can you please tell me how should the download be, and how do I implement this loading effect.

Main_activty

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    public static String[] name = new String[5];

    public static String[] pic = new String[5];

    int z = 1;
    public static int  zimgload ;
    String ab;
//  public static Bitmap btm;
    public static Bitmap[] btm = new Bitmap[5];

    public static ImageView imageview;

    public static TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         zimgload = 0;
            textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            load();
            textView.setText(name[0]);
            //imageview.setImageBitmap(btm[0]);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void next(View v) throws Exception {
        if (z<5){
            textView.setText(name[z]);

            imageview.setImageBitmap(btm[z]);
            z++;
            }
            else
            {z=1;
             zimgload = 0;

            load();
            textView.setText(name[0]);
            imageview.setImageBitmap(btm[0]);

            }



    }

    void load(){

        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {

            try {
                Jsonfromserver jsondata = new Jsonfromserver();
                String result = jsondata.getdata();

                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                name = new String[jArray.length()];

                pic = new String[jArray.length()];


                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Pulling items from the array
                    name[i] = oneObject.getString("name");
                    small[i] = oneObject.getString("small");

                    }
                    new ImageDownloader().execute(small[0]);








            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }


    class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... param) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return downloadBitmap(param[0]);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i("Async-Example", "onPreExecute Called");
            // simpleWaitDialog =
            // ProgressDialog.show(ImageDownladerActivity.this,"Wait",
            // "Downloading Image");

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            Log.i("Async-Example", "onPostExecute Called"+zimgload);
            //ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            if (zimgload==0)
            {imageview.setImageBitmap(result);}

            if (zimgload<5)
            {
            btm[zimgload] = result;


            zimgload++;
            if (zimgload!=5)
            {new ImageDownloader().execute(small[zimgload]); }
            Log.i("noiw", "in if"+zimgload);
            }
            else{
                Log.i("else", "ooooooo"+zimgload);
                zimgload=1; 
                }


            //imageview.setImageBitmap(btm);
            // simpleWaitDialog.dismiss();

        }

        private Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
            // initilize the default HTTP client object
            final DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // forming a HttoGet request
            final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
            try {

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);

                // check 200 OK for success
                final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode
                            + " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
                    return null;

                }

                final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                if (entity != null) {
                    InputStream inputStream = null;
                    try {
                        // getting contents from the stream
                        inputStream = entity.getContent();

                        // decoding stream data back into image Bitmap that
                        // android understands
                        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory
                                .decodeStream(inputStream);

                        return bitmap;
                    } finally {
                        if (inputStream != null) {
                            inputStream.close();
                        }
                        entity.consumeContent();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // You Could provide a more explicit error message for
                // IOException
                getRequest.abort();
                Log.e("ImageDownloader",
                        "Something went wrong while retrieving bitmap from "
                                + url + e.toString());
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Jsonformserver class

```
public class Jsonfromserver {

    public String getdata(){
    DefaultHttpClient   httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.xxx.com/api/randomimage.php");
    // Depends on your web service
    httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = null;
    try {
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);           
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    inputStream = entity.getContent();
    // json is UTF-8 by default i beleive
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    result = sb.toString();
    }

    catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();
}
    return result;

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lazy loading images gets very complex very quickly. There are always improvements to be made.

The best off the shelf solution which I encourage you to try before rolling your own would be

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

It's still not perfect, even I have gone with a custom solution after using the above library, but it's certainly close for most apps needs.